# changing the variable type from NaN to a number JavaScript

Tags: nan, parseint

I have such a strange situation, I changed the variable "x" to a number using parseInt and it works but when displaying the variable it shows me NaN and while in the form I enter 3 and I would like to add 2, instead of displaying 5 it also shows NaN

```
first number: <input type="number" id="PL">
```

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("PL").value)
```

```
console.log(typeof(x)) //number
console.log(x) //NaN
```

Comment: Please check the both values typeof first then proceed

Comment: Have you made sure that the element "PL" exists? NaN is a numeric value but it means that the conversion is somehow wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KubaPilat/23rL4a9q/3/